# Is it possible to kill CPLEX from outside?

Tags: cplex

Is it possible to stop CPLEX resolution from an external command and if yes, how ? I just want CPLEX to be killed without having any current result.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which 'CPLEX'? Do you mean the CPLEX studio, the command-line version oplrun, the cplex command-line solver, or a copy of cplex built into your own code using an API? (and if so, what language are you using?). What platform (Windows, Linux, etc?)

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick I am using CPLEX with Netbeans inside Spring Framework and the language in which CPLEX is used is Java. It's working on Windows (mostly)

Comment: I think you're looking for the [Aborter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.Aborter.html) class. Take a look at the MIPex4.java example to see how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The nicest way to kill a running cplex that is called using an API such as java is probably to create a callback in CPLEX that will get called frequently and inside the callback you can test for some standard variable being set to a specific value and then terminate the search process. In your non-cplex java code you can set that variable in response to anything you want such as a user interrupt or some timeout, and then some (short) time later the callback should see that value and stop cplex in a tidy manner.